# Putting the data in descending order in a barplot made with plot_ly

Tags: r, plot, plotly, bar-chart

I did an interactive bar plot with plot_ly() and I wanted to have the bar in descending order of the number of arrests. To do so I have arranged my data before but it is not working and run the code.

Do you know what can I do to make it work ?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
plot2 <- plotly:: plot_ly(crime_data2, x = ~state, y = ~violent_crime, type = 'bar', name = 'Number of violent crimes') %>%  plotly::add_trace(y = ~non_violent_crime, name = 'Number of non violent crimes') %>%
layout(title= list(text = "Violent VS Non-Violent crime in the US"), 
                     legend=list(title=list(text='Type of crime')), 
                xaxis = list(title = list(text ='State')),yaxis =list(title = list(text ='Number of crimes (in millions)')),plot_bgcolor='#e5ecf6')
```

Thank you Folks !

Answer (score 0):

In general reordering your data will have no effect on the order of your chart. If not otherwise given your categories aka states will be ordered alphabetically. If you want a specific order you have to convert to a `factor` which for example could be achieved via `reorder` which allows to order a variable by a second, numeric variable.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)

crime_data2 <- data.frame(
  state = sample(state.name, 50),
  violent_crime = runif(50),
  non_violent_crime = runif(50)
)
# Order states in descending order by number of violent crimes 
crime_data2$state <- reorder(crime_data2$state, -crime_data2$violent_crime)

plotly::plot_ly(crime_data2, x = ~state, y = ~violent_crime, type = "bar", name = "Number of violent crimes") %>%
  plotly::add_trace(y = ~non_violent_crime, name = "Number of non violent crimes") %>%
  layout(
    title = list(text = "Violent VS Non-Violent crime in the US"),
    legend = list(title = list(text = "Type of crime")),
    xaxis = list(title = list(text = "State")), yaxis = list(title = list(text = "Number of crimes (in millions)")), plot_bgcolor = "#e5ecf6"
  )
```

[image]